# Make ICollection work as IList

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I am trying to use MvvmLight to do ViewModel binding in Xamarin Android

MvvmLight accepts IList as a parameter for data-binding, but all the viewmodels are using ICollection (The app was initially windows only and currently migrating to Android, we cannot change the ICollection to IList)

I know IList extends ICollection, so..I guess this is more of a pattern-ish thing, what is the best way that we make those ICollection work as IList?

Casting is the obvious solution, but not all ICollection implements IList so we are trying to avoid that

We also cannot make a copy of the original collection because we need two-way binding

Comment: You can create a wrapper implementing IList that routes calls to the underlying collection.  This could also take care of partially emulating indexing (assuming Xamarin uses this) with ElementAt.  This breaks down if the consuming implementation tries to do insertion, though, since you cannot perform random-access insertion; you would need to reconstruct the entire Collection in that case by removing everything, then adding it back again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no guarantee that an arbitrary `ICollection<T>` is also an `IList<T>`, the easiest way is to use the [Adapter Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter): Write a thin shim that provides the interface that you need (`IList<T>`).

`IList<T>` is a pretty simple interface and you should be able to do something along these lines (see example below), though one might note that `IList<T>` provides certain features that are simply not compatible with arbitrary `ICollection<T>` implementations. Depending on what specific `IList<T>` features the consumer(s) use, you may throw `NotSupportedException`s.

One might also note that you could get a little smarter in your adapter and use *reflection* to interrogate the backing store for its actual capabilities — my example below does a simple version, trying to cast the backing store to `IList<T>` and using that knowledge where it can.

```
class ListAdapter<T> : IList<T>
{
    private readonly ICollection<T> backingStore;
    private readonly IList<T> list;

    public ListAdapter( ICollection<T> collection )
    {
        if ( collection == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
        this.backingStore = collection ;
        this.list = collection as IList<T> ;

    }

    public int IndexOf( T item )
    {
        if ( list == null ) throw new NotSupportedException() ;
        return list.IndexOf(item) ;
    }

    public void Insert( int index , T item )
    {
        if ( list == null ) throw new NotSupportedException() ;
        list.Insert(index,item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt( int index )
    {
        if ( list == null ) throw new NotSupportedException() ;
        list.RemoveAt(index) ;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if ( list == null ) throw new NotSupportedException() ;
            return list[index] ;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( list == null ) throw new NotSupportedException() ;
            list[index] = value ;
        }
    }

    public void Add( T item )
    {
        backingStore.Add(item) ;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        backingStore.Clear() ;
    }

    public bool Contains( T item )
    {
        return backingStore.Contains(item) ;
    }

    public void CopyTo( T[] array , int arrayIndex )
    {
        backingStore.CopyTo( array , arrayIndex ) ;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return backingStore.Count ; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            if ( list == null ) throw new NotSupportedException() ;
            return list.IsReadOnly ;
        }
    }

    public bool Remove( T item )
    {
        return backingStore.Remove(item) ;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return backingStore.GetEnumerator() ;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)backingStore).GetEnumerator() ;
    }

}
```